# Incorrect indentation for tag listing questions loaded via AJAX

Tags: bug, status-completed, user-interface

I am seeing a weird indentation for questions loaded via AJAX (i.e., by clicking the *`n question(s) with new activity`* link).

The following screenshot was taken before I clicked the link:

[image]

And this is after the new question was loaded:

[image]

A browser refresh resolves the problem (as can be expected).

It was tested with Chrome 88 and Firefox 85 on [macOS 10.15](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MacOS_Catalina) (Catalina).

Comment: The `<div class="mln24">` wrapper is missing on fetched questions.

Comment: Also reported on MSO: [New questions displayed offset to existing ones when using "new activity" link](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/405536/4642212).

Comment: We're going to look into this as part of our regular bug duty rotation. Thanks for the report!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This is fixed. Tag listing questions (and only tag listing questions) loaded through real-time-api calls are now properly left-margined.

> `div` neg-left-margin
> now being applied per-spec
> twenty four pixels