# Questions overlapping with left nav in every sub-tab under the 'Questions' tab

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, tabs, left-nav

This seems to be happening on every SE site whenever I visit the "Questions" tab [on Chrome]:

[Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions):

[image]

---

[English Language and Usage Stack Exchange](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions):

[image]

And basically every other site in the network...

This happens in every sub-tab under the "Questions" tab:

[image]

Comment: I guess they fixed [this bug](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/361403/289905) twice as hard as they should… Jokes aside — maybe they’re in the process of fixing it.

Comment: Cross-site duplicate on MSO: [Question list missing left margin/padding](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/406171/4642212).

Comment: I had just noticed this myself ... seeing the same thing. Using Chrome as a browser. It has nothing to do with width either, as I opened the browser up to well over 3000 pixels wide with the same effect (on Mechanics).

Comment: From Adam Lear on [cross site dupe](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/406171/question-list-missing-left-margin-padding?noredirect=1#comment832669_406171): *"Yeah... that's broken. I'm reverting the change that's causing this."*

Comment: I'm singing The Time Warp in my head - "It's just a jump to the left". Can we now have the step to the right please.

Comment: The cause seems to be an additional `mln24` class on new questions in the feed.

Comment: [The three alignments](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MWRfy.png) (with some posts in between removed).

Comment: Yay, I can use the burger menu again! ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This has been fixed. Staff wrote a [response on MSO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/406174) and on [MSE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/362541).
A good screenshot of how the bug looked was also included in the comments, it's worth linking it here:

[image: screenshot of question listing]