# Content overflow on left sidebar

Tags: support, bug

Today I am seeing this on my google chrome & Mozilla  Firefox browser both..

[image]

[image]

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Non-alignment of questions in the 'questions' tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/362416/non-alignment-of-questions-in-the-questions-tab)