# Questions overlapping with left nav after clicking on "n question(s) with new activity"

Tags: bug, design, regression, left-nav

I noticed this on Meta Stack Exchange in particular and it started happening a couple of hours ago:

[image]

After clicking on "n question(s) with new activity", the questions overlap with the left navigation bar. (Reloading the page resolves the issue..)

As mentioned in the comments below, this is a regression of [Questions overlapping with left nav in every sub-tab under the 'Questions' tab](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/362416/289905).

Comment: This was happening the other day, but as far as I'm aware, it already got fixed. It's possible you have a cached version of the broken CSS. Try clearing your browser cache.

Comment: @F1Krazy - This only started happening a few hours ago.. It was working fine yesterday..

Comment: @F1Krazy No, it’s not the browser cache. This is a reproducible recent regression that started happening a couple hours ago.

Comment: Reproduced here as well, on FF on Mac

Comment: @SebastianSimon - I think it's fixed now..

Comment: Agreed @Justin.

Comment: Yeah, I think this was hand-in-hand with the AJAX load, so it should be fixed.